# training a decision tree

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to get started with Machine Learning.

I have some training data representing pixel values of digits in images and I am trying to train a decision tree out of this. What would be a good way of getting started? What tools should I consider (pointers on related documentation would help)?

I also want to train a random forest on the data to compare performance versus decision tree. Any guidance would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get started is probably [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). Apart from offering implementations of a random forest classifier as well as several decision trees (among lots of other algorithms), it also provides tools for processing and visualizing the data. It comes with a relatively easy to use GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The random forest uses trees, so I'd probably counsel you to get the trees working first. Once you know all about trees, you can read about forests and it will be very straightforward. However, you should start by trying to learn about machine learning rather than just jumping into a library. I would start by understanding how to use decision trees on Boolean features (much simpler) using the method of maximizing entropy. Once you understand that algorithm well enough to run it by hand on a small dataset, read up on how to use decision-trees on real valued features. Then check out the library.